# C++ pattern for class members that may only be modified in operator=()

Tags: c++

I would like to be able to declare a class member that can only be modified in constructors or in the assignment operator. The `const` declaration does not work because of the assignment issue.

```cpp
   
   class foo
   {
      const int x;
   public:
      foo(int inp) : x(inp) {}
      foo(const foo &src) : x(src.x) {}
      foo& operator=(foo&src)
      {
         x = src.x; //compiler error (not desired)
         return *this;
      }
      
      void bar()
      {
         x = 4;  //compiler error (desired)
      }
   };
```

Does anyone know an elegant design pattern that can accomplish this? I find `const` members to be extremely limited in their usefulness. But if there were a pattern that allowed for modifying a member only in `operator=` while giving errors anywhere else it was modified, I would probably make a lot of use of it.

Comment: What about making only constructor and `operator=` public?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to construct a new object, and assign that to `*this`?

Comment: My goal is to prevent the code of the class itself from modifying the member, and the scope of the constructor and ```operator=``` don't affect it.

Comment: The most pristine answer would be to refactor my code not to allow ```operator=```. Then  ```const``` would do the job. But refactoring is a big job.

Answer (score 1):

You could mark `x` as `private` and then implement all your other methods in a class derived from `foo`:

```
class foo
{
private:
    int x;
protected:
    int y;
public:
    foo(int inp) : x(inp) {}
    foo(const foo &src) : x(src.x) {}
    foo& operator=(foo&src)
    {
         x = src.x;
         return *this;
    }
};

class derived : public foo
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        x = 4;  // compiler error (desired)
        y = 42; // ok
    }
};
```

Comment: A getter for `x` could also be useful here.

Comment: @bipll Absolutely.  I won't add it here to keep the post focussed.

Comment: Yes this would work. But it adds a lot of complexity when the goal is to add simplicity.

Comment: Complexity?  One additional class?

Comment: One additional class *per class*. I was hoping for a pattern that can be generalized throughout the code base.